# tabu X column with negative width coefficient and footnotes too wide

Tags: footnotes, tabu, longtabu

When using tabu X columns one can specify negative coefficients to shrink the columns to their natural width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{|X[-1]|X|}
\hline
Text & Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text.\\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image: Basic version]

But as soon as you add a footnote in the column with the negative coefficient (here the first) it behaves as if there were no negative coefficient:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{|X[-1]|X|}
\hline
Text\footnote{Foo Bar} &
Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text.\\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image: Footnote version]

How can get the table to have the column widths from the first example when using footnotes?

Please note that although these examples use the `tabu` environment, I want to use a `longtabu` where the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{|X[-1]|X|}
\hline
Text\footnotemark[1] &
Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text.\\
\hline
\end{tabu}
    \footnotetext[1]{Foo Bar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: In `tabu` documentation is warning, that footnotes is not implemented yet (I didn't test this).

Comment: In the documentation it says “The syntax `\footnote ...` is allowed in `tabu` and `longtabu`” and adds then “this is not implemented for `longtable` yet”.

Comment: But thanks, this works beside the minor issue that now all footnotes are placed at the end of the table.